# Why the client will block while fetching image continually from server with Netty?

Tags: java, networking, netty

I want to show remote desktop on the client in real time. That is server sending screenshot continually and client painting the image on the panel at the same time. It works well at the beginning, but the client will block after a few minutes and the server is normally.

The class CaptureImage defined for screenshot. It has two attributes, length and content.

```
private int length;// The length of attribute content
private byte[] content;// The BufferedImage convert to bytearray
```

The main code of server:

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage image;
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, toolkit.getScreenSize().width, toolkit.getScreenSize().height);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CaptureImage captureImage = new CaptureImage();
        while (true) {
            image = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
            captureImage.setLength(baos.toByteArray().length);
            captureImage.setContent(baos.toByteArray());
            ctx.writeAndFlush(captureImage);// Deliver to ImageEncoder before writing
            Thread.sleep(100);
            baos.reset();
            // Always print if add System.out.println() here...
        }
    }
}

public class ImageEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<CaptureImage> {
    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, CaptureImage msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        out.writeInt(msg.getLength());
        out.writeBytes(msg.getContent());
    }
}
```

The main code of client:

```
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        // Accept msg from ImageDecoder
        CaptureImage captureImage = (CaptureImage) msg;
        RemoteDesktop.panel.display(captureImage.getContent());// Paint the image on the panel
    }
}

public class ImageDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void> {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        int length = in.readInt();

        byte[] content = new byte[length];
        in.readBytes(content);

        CaptureImage captureImage = new CaptureImage();
        captureImage.setLength(length);
        captureImage.setContent(content);

        out.add(captureImage);
        // The print will stop after a few minutes if add System.out.println() here...
    }
}
```

The print in ServerHandler always going on, but the print in ImageDecoder maybe stop after a few minutes.

The problem I encountered looks like OutOfMemoryError. But there isn't any ERROR MESSAGE even if I override exceptionCaught method in every ChannelHandler. And I also tried Memory Analyzer but it seems no help.

Please help me to find the crucial reason.

The runnable project is here https://github.com/leisuredong/RemoteDesktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the server is sending the images too fast and the client is slow. In this case the client will go out of memory because of the client's inbound netty buffer getting filled.

A better design for the server code would be to await an ack from the client (within a given time period) before sending the next message. Client could send an ack when it has finished processing the current message.